# Remotely manage mobile-broadband-connected linux host

Tags: linux, networking, remote-access, 3g

I have a remote Linux host that is connected to the internet via mobile broadband, and hence does not allow incoming connections.
Does anyone know if there is a service that could allow me to remotely connect to such a host?
I know logmein achieves this for Windows, but I do not know of a similar service for Linux.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Nick

Comment: Not constructive in its current form. Please define what you need for remote administration a bit better.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I'd try would be [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net) (the software, not their service). In a worst-case scenario, running OpenVPN over TCP would cause the remote host to maintain a persistent TCP connection with your OpenVPN server, insuring that you always have an open "pipe" out to the client (not unlike what LogMeIn and services of that type are doing by maintaining "always-on" connections back to their central servers).

Comment: And if you're running on battery, be sure to tune OpenVPN as it can be very aggressive about making sure the network is up, which will cause the radio to eat battery very rapidly.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this. Looks like a robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a SSH reverse tunnel from the remote host.

You can use autossh or similar to keep it active.

You can tunnel any other protocol over SSH.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Colin. Looks like an easy option to set up.